# Suggested Edits taking too long to get through the system

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

I have recently gone on a tag-wiki editing spree, as I noticed that many of the tags were empty. But, even though these edits were made over 10 hours ago, I see that no one has actually reviewed them.

**How can we bring light to this editing issue?**

Comment: The first time I have holiday in months and you moan about it?! :P

Answer (score 5):

First off I would like to thank you for suggesting so many wonderful edits. Tag wikis are a fundamental part of the site as they help define a topic. And having a well defined set of wikis helps people get more out of the site.

Secondly I'm sorry that your edits have languished in the queue. I've gone ahead and reviewed them for you. Part of the problem is that we have few who can actually approve tag wikis. Compared to regular reviewing it takes 1500 reputation to review tag wikis. As of this posting we have 15 people who can approve such edits. Sadly this means that we can't approve such edits as fast as we would like.

I hope I have answered your question. If you have any more don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: You said that tag-wiki's are needed to help define a topic. How exactly are they helpful? Do you have any examples? (Sorry for the badly phrased question, I am trying to multitask.)

Comment: Well try asking a new question. Whenever you try to add a tag a little blurb pops up telling you what the tag covers.